# Recursive formula with a function inside of it

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'd like to preface this with the fact that I'm noobish at coding.

My problem is that I'd like to generate a new value of a sequence with a function inside the recursive formula (in python).

The sequence is given by
[this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsOYR.png) and I defined the necessary function in the picture p by:

[image]

```
import math
def p (k, q):
    if math.gcd(k, q) == q:
         return 1
    elif math.gcd(k, q) == 1:
         return q 
    else:
        return alpha
```

and "alpha" in the code block above is just some integer that's produced in earlier part of the whole program. Now, my question is how could I produce for a given an integer n, its corresponding value given by the formula where the first three values of the sequence are

> `k_1 = 1, k_2 = 2, and k_3 = 6.`

---

EDIT: The background to this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
# Find's the prime factorization of any given integer n,
# where the list depicts the necessary multiples to determine the factorization.
def prime_factors(q):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= q:
        if q % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            q //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if q > 1:
        factors.append(q)
    return factors

q = 6

pf = prime_factors(q)
print("The prime factorization of q is: " + str(pf))

# Reducing the prime factorization of q to only considering its prime factors and "getting rid of" the exponents
res = []
for i in pf:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
alpha = np.prod(np.array(res))

print("The result of applying the function α is: " + str(alpha))

#Defining the function p
def p (k, q):
    global alpha
    if math.gcd(k, q) == q:
         return 1
    elif math.gcd(k, q) == 1:
         return q 
    else:
        return alpha   

# Don't know how to produce the following k_q depending on a choice of q
print("The number at the last of the following list is k_n: [?] ") 

# The list should look like: k_1 = 1, k_2 = 2, k_3 = 6, k_4 = 12, k_5 = 60, k_6 = 60, k_7 = 420, ... and so on

>> The prime factorization of q is: [2, 3]
>> The result of applying the function α is: 6
>> The number at the last of the following list is k_q: [?]
```

Comment: shouldn't be k in gcd, but k[n-1]

Comment: First let `k = [1, 2, 6]`, then `for _ in range(n - 3): k.append(k[-1] * p(k[-1]))`.

Comment: @002 please check if the answer I provided is suitable for you. If yes please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a for loop along with a function to calculate next number in the series should be sufficient. I have assumed `alpha = 1`

The output I get for first 6 terms of the series is:

```
[1, 2, 6, 6, 30]
```

---

Code:

```
import math

alpha = 1
def p (k, q):
    global alpha
    if math.gcd(k, q) == q:
        return 1
    elif math.gcd(k, q) == 1:
        return q
    else:
        return alpha

def get_next_num(k_prev, n):
    k_next = k_prev*p(k_prev, n)
    return k_next

k_prev = 1 #Since you said the first term of the series is 1
arr = []
for n in range(1, 6):
    k_new = get_next_num(k_prev, n)
    arr.append(k_new)
    k_prev=k_new

print(arr)
```